# localstorage or sessionstorage can't persist data on cross browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a small application but I am stuck on a problem.  I want stored form element values on a HTML page when filled in on one browser(Ex. Firefox) and auto fill data when same page is loaded in another browser(Ex. Chrome).  If anybody has any ideas please help me.

Comment: My first thought is have you tried using cookies?

Comment: If you want to pass data from one browser to another one, you'll need to go through your server.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake as cookies have space limitation,i am directly used localstorage concept..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless clients can login and you're willing to share this data via your server, you can not change behavior of a different browser from your current, so in your example Firefox can not change a cookie, localstorage or whatever of Chrome. Browsers tend to only share information like cookies when they are first ran; such as with you the import wizard from Firefox.

I can think of two alternatives to achieve this:

- An authentication system where the data is stored server-side.
- Through custom browser extensions. You could create a custom browser extension that directly writes the data of the other browsers. This does require the user to install that extension though.

Answer (score -2):

This link explain how to achieve that http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

It's not simple, but it's the way that I know it can be done at the moment without the use of cookies.

Comment: i have already seen this link but doesn't solve my problem, have you face this problem? how did you solve this problem by above link or anything else...